# AJAX xmlhttp.open Not Running Script

Tags: php, javascript, html, xml, ajax

I am modifying the tutorial found here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp
so that the library of autocomplete names are stored on a database. I added a button which allows the user to add a name to the database if it is not already in the database. When I click the button, the method fires, however the php script designated in the addName() method does not execute. This is strange because the script defined in the showHint() method does execute. Here is my javascript (this is all that is necessary to be shown). I have omitted the scripts:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showHint(str)
        {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (str.length==0)
            {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
                return;
            }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }

        function addName(str){
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","addName.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Start typing a name in the input field below:</h3>
<form action="">
    First name: <input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" />
</form>
<p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
<button type="button" onclick="addName(document.getElementById('txt1').value)">Add Name</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think jquery ajax is more better then javascript ajax to use....

Comment: Do you have Chrome or some other browser with developer tools? You should open the Chrome Developer Tools (or equivalent). Using Chrome do this: F12, click the Network tab then click your button. You should see the request being made. You can click on it to see the response. Maybe PHP is outputting an error. You can check for that and let us know your findings here if you can't fix it yourself with that information :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
  function getXhr() {
      var xmlhttp;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else { // code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      return xmlhttp;
  }

  function showHint(str) {
      var xmlhttp;
      if (str.length==0) {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
          return;
      }
      xmlhttp = getXhr();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= function() {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
      };
      xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
  }

  function addName(str) {
      var xmlhttp = getXhr();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= function() {
         ...your logic here...
      };
      xmlhttp.open("GET","addName.php?q="+str, true);
      xmlhttp.send();
  }
```

Comment: Why do I need to implement logic in the onreadystatechange function? All i want to do is run a php script. I am not concerned with when the readystate changes. This does fix the problem though. I just don't understand why I need it.

Comment: Hmm, I understand now.  I don't know why addName was not working for you.  It could be that my re-factoring has corrected some other latent problem that was lurking in your code. Without actually trying it in a debugger (F12 browser tools for FF, Chrome. IE) I could only guess. In any case it's good to use proper coding practices, like factoring out commonly used logic into functions (`getXhr()`).  Be careful about relying on W3schools - they often show bad practices and in some cases the information is flatly incorrect.

Comment: More and more I've been hearing this about W3schools! but yes even after refactoring the code as you have suggested I have this strange thing happening: with no code in the area where you have written "...your logic here...", the script never runs. However when I insert the exact same logic from the showHint() method, the script does run. Very stange. Such a simple goal. All I want is to run a php script on buttonpress!

Answer (score 0):

Add a onreadystatechange and look at the http status call and see if it is an error.

Use a tool like Fiddler or Firebug to see if the request goes out.

And you should be url encoding the `str`.

Comment: Adding onreadystatechange and implementing logic inside the call solves the problem. But why? Is this just a rule of AJAX? Clearly I do not explicitly need the onreadystatechange method, since all I want to do is run a script on the server onclick.

Answer (score 0):

Please change in your code this way

```
<form action="">
    First name: <input type="text" id="txt1" value="ABC-XYZ" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" />
</form>
```

Comment: Okay this works. The script ran. Please tell me why this works though... very strange fix.

Comment: because in your function showHint(str) check the condition 
 if (str.length==0) and if it is true the it clear the innerhtml and return so nothing is happened

Comment: if this my answer is helpful to you give it correct and 1+ up so it will be helpful to others

Comment: Wait. Nevermind. This was not the fix. The fix was actually that I must define onreadystatechange as a function with actual logic inside.

Comment: Oh! i see.... Its okay no prob dear. I just want to helpfull to all our community